# Automation - Testing the Contents in EMail

Tags: selenium, java, selenium-webdriver, email

In my application I am supposed to test/fetch the data  and contents of the E-Mail received after triggering the Schedule.
How can I automate this scenario using Selenium web-driver ?

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6630/how-to-automate-testing-of-received-emails?rq=1

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/is-mail-testing-with-selenium-possible?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

To automate Email, you can use javax mail API for fetching the email from the inbox or any other folder.

Following is the function for fetching an email.

```
private Message getEmail(String emailID, String password, String subjectToBeSearched) throws Exception {
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", emailID, password);

Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

Message[] messages = null;
boolean mailFound = false;
Message email = null;

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    messages = folder.search(new SubjectTerm(subjectToBeSearched), folder.getMessages());
    if (messages.length == 0) {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}

for (Message mail : messages) {
    if (!mail.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {
        email = mail;
        mailFound = true;
    }
}

if (!mailFound) {
    throw new Exception("Could not found Email");
}

return email;
}
```

You can call this function by passing email Id and Password, It will return you an email.

Then you can perform various operation on the return object, for example:

```
public verifyEmail() throws Exception {
Message email = getEmail(emailID, password, "Subject of Email to be 

searched");
System.out.println(email.getAllRecipients());
System.out.println(email.getContent());
System.out.println(email.getSubject());

// and many more functions
    }
```

Following is the link to download the javax mail API

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4.7

or you can use maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```